# Expand collapsed div again on toggle

Tags: jquery

I have a div which collapses, but needs to expand again when hitting the toggle button again. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/100pvu95/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
        $("#sidebar").animate({
            left: '-55%'
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#toggle").click(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $("#sidebar").animate({
                left: '0%'
        });
        }else{
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $("#sidebar").animate({
                left: '-55%'
        });
        }


        });
    });
```

Try This js code.

http://jsfiddle.net/100pvu95/3/   See here

Comment: This works well. But one thing. I am using media queries which let the sidebar have more or less width size, depending on the screen size. Therefore your code will, after clicking toggle, not always leave as much of the sidebar on screen depending on the screen size. Is there a way to not tell the sidebar how far over to move, but to tell it how much to leave in screen? Hope I have explained it well enough.

Answer (score 5):

you can use this code 
you must declare a variable for control click of button

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var is_Clicked = false;
      $("#toggle").click(function() {
        if (is_Clicked) {
          $("#sidebar").animate({
            left: '0'
          });
          is_Clicked = false;
        } else {
          $("#sidebar").animate({
            left: '-55%'
          });
          is_Clicked = true;
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 70%;
  height: 80%;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#toggle {
  width: 10%;
  height: 40%;
  margin-right: 6.5%;
  margin-top: 3.5%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">

  SIDEBAR
  <input type="button" value="Toggle" id="toggle">
</div>
```

Comment: This works well. But one thing. I am using media queries which let the sidebar have more or less width size, depending on the screen size. Therefore your code will, after clicking toggle, not always leave as much of the sidebar on screen depending on the screen size. Is there a way to not tell the sidebar how far over to move, but to tell it how much to leave in screen? Hope I have explained it well enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit fuzzy on my jquery, but you can make 2 classes with the css properties you want for open and close and then toggle the classes on the `.click()` event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#toggle").click(function () {
    $("#sidebar").toggleClass("close");

});
});
```

CSS

```
.open{
  width: 0px
}
.close{
  width: -70px;
}
```

Just make sure to declare the `.close class` after the `.open class`
so it overwrites the properties of the`.open class` when it your div is added to it

Something like this should work, the code may need some tweaking cause I'm a bit rusty on my jQuery, but there you go.